# Where do I put seed data if I have already created my database in my Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, seed

I’m using Rials 4.2.5.  I want to create some seed data for a new model, user_images, I just created in an existing project.  However, I already have a db/seeds.rb file that has been run on my database.  Where do I put the seed data for this new model?  I assume i can’t use db/seeds.rb because it has already been run.  It is not an option to blow away the database and start again.

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a custom rake task in lib/tasks. The file should end in .rake. Then you run it by the name. For example:

```
task :do_something => :environment do
  p "do something"
end
```

You'd run this task by calling `rake do_something` in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use seeds.. I use, for example:

```
Person.find_or_create_by(name: 'Bob')
```

Lots of them, as required, then run as many times as I like.. I run seeds on each auto deployment for example, so I don't forget..

Link to command: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by

Comment: That's a useful command, but hwere are you putting it, in db/seeds.rb ?

Comment: Yup. Straight in there. Update your current seeds to the same format. That way they also will be there, and if you ever do need blow away the db, they'll come back.